# Can I switch to wondows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8

My computer is running the latest version of Ubuntu. Can I install windows 8 and clean off Ubuntu? I don't want to duel boot.

Comment: If the Windows license allows you to do so, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can be able to cleanoff Ubuntu and install Windows.

[How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)